# CSS arrow positioning different in different browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-position

The position of the arrow line changes in different browsers. Can we solve this. I have used `position:relative` on the parent so **this is not a duplicate question.**

This works perfectly in **Chrome** but in **Firefox** it's an another story, the line following the arrow(: before) changes its position slightly to left. Can we solve this.?

```css
span{
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-weight: 600;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 12px;
    color:#00C16D;
}
span.up:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 4.5px solid rgba(181, 41, 41, 0);
    border-bottom: 8px solid #00C16D;
    border-right: 4.5px solid rgba(221, 221, 221, 0);
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
}
span.up:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 3px solid #00C16D;
    bottom: 3px;
    left: 11%;
    height: 8px;
}
```

```html
<span class="up">Up</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is due to *pixel-rounding* due to the use of fractional pixel values

```
span.up:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 4.5px solid rgba(181, 41, 41, 0);
    border-bottom: 8px solid #00C16D;
    border-right: 4.5px solid rgba(221, 221, 221, 0);
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Try using *whole pixel values*.

Comment: This solution worked out fine for me. Changed the `4.5px` to `4px` and some other changes in the code and now all browsers are taking same `position`.